# Angular phonecat. Jsonp callback

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

Learning angular textbook on the official site. Annex phonecat phone list is taken from the json file in the folder.

I wrote serverside and deploy to heroku. The application issues a valid json.

How do I make a request to the server? Using the method JSONP? Below is the code I wrote as I did, but it does not work. Help me please.

**It work:**

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var url = 'phones/phones.json';
  $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
 });
```

It don't work

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
var url = 'http://MyServerSideOnHeroku.com/phones.json';
 $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
   $scope.phones = data;
});
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

For the $http.jsonp, the url should contain "JSON_CALLBACK".!!

Check the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

And in your case, the Url should be:

```
var url = 'http://MyServerSideOnHeroku.com/phones.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
```

Comment: Ok. Add ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK - dont't work. My link https://secret-coast-8851.herokuapp.com/phones.json

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting? Post your code somewhere in fiddle/plunker so that i can fix the issue.